# Why does my add-on work from the 'Add' menu in the header but not from Shift+A?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

My modal addon is using `raycast`, I've taken a function from Blender python templates: everything worked fine. However when I try to add my addon to `Add` menu (`VIEW3D_MT_add`), it starts to act weird: I think that the issue is with contexts, but I don't know how to solve this.

Here's a stripped down test code:

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
"name": "Test Addon", 
"category": "Object",
"version": (0, 0, 1),
"blender": (2, 80, 0),}

class OBJECT_OT_my_addon(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_addon"
    bl_label = "My Addon Name"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
      print(context.region_data)
      return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    # self.layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
    self.layout.operator("object.my_addon")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_my_addon)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_my_addon)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.remove(menu_func)
```

`context.region_data` is needed for raycast, so this addon prints it out.

When I run it from Viewport Add menu, it prints out `RegionView3D`: everything is fine. However if I run it from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add menu, I'm getting an error:

`ERROR (wm.operator): c:\b\win64_cmake_vs2017\win64_cmake_vs2017\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.c:1486 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OBJECT_OT_my_addon'`

if I uncomment the `self.layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` in `menu_func`, it starts working fine from the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> menu and prints out `RegionView3D`, but! if I run it from Viewport Add menu it prints `None` and my raycast doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The menu is in the header region**

Put together this for prior version of this question. Can also get the region 3d view from `space_data.region_3d` or `area.spaces.active.region_3d`

When invoked from the header the region will be the header.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils
from mathutils import Vector

bl_info = {
"name": "Test Addon", 
"category": "Object",
"version": (0, 0, 1),
"blender": (2, 80, 0),}

def get_v(context, event):
    scene = context.scene
    area = context.area
    region = area.regions[-1] # or search for region.type == 'WINDOW'
    space = area.spaces.active
    rv3d = space.region_3d
    print(context.region.type, rv3d == context.region_data) # See Output
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y

    print(region, rv3d, coord)

class OBJECT_OT_my_addon(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_addon"
    bl_label = "My Addon Name"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
      print(get_v(context, event))
      return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
    self.layout.operator("object.my_addon")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_my_addon)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_my_addon)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The See Output print above from header menu

```
HEADER False
```

and from <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> menu

```
WINDOW True
```

To sum up, only use `context.region_data` if you are sure you are in the 3D view window. Python console code, `a` is a view3d area

```
>>> a.type
'VIEW_3D'

>>> for r in a.regions:
...     r.type
...     
'TOOL_HEADER'
'HEADER'
'TOOLS'
'UI'
'WINDOW'
```

Another method would be to use `'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'` as the operator context, to make sure the `'WINDOW'` region is used.

Comment: Aaah. Ooohh!! Thank you! Both menus and raycast work now

Comment: @batFinger Tried to come up with a more specific title for the question - feel free to replace it if you have a better one.

Comment: Will do.  @SergeyKritskiy prob should mention `INVOKE_REGION_WIN` prob fixes this too.